# Sorting Custom Objects with Collections.sort()

Tags: java

I am trying to sort custom objects using Collections.sort in java and I am running into this error, with the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class StudentClient {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
      students.add(new Student("Jasper Holton", 12));
      students.add(new Student("John Doe", 10));
      ArrayList<Student> sortedStudents = Collections.sort(students);
      System.out.println(sortedStudents);
   }
}
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
   public String name;
   public int id;
   public Student(String name){
      this.name = name;
   }
   public Student(String name, int id){
      this.name = name;
      this.id = id;
   }
   ...
   @Override
   public int compareTo(Student s){
      return s.id - this.id;
   }
}
```

This is the error:

```
StudentClient.java:14: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to ArrayList<Student>
      ArrayList<Student> sortedStudents = Collections.sort(students);
```

How do I fix this error? Why is collections.sort returning a void type?

Comment: it sorts the existing list, it doesn't create a new one

Comment: "Why is collections.sort returning a void type?" Because that's what the documentation says it does. You should try reading the documentation in order to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is a compile time error. `sort` works on the same list you provide, it doesn't return a new one.

So just change this:

```
ArrayList<Student> sortedStudents = Collections.sort(students);
System.out.println(sortedStudents);
```

For this

```
Collections.sort(students);
System.out.println(students);
```

**Update**: Reference documentation

All java classes are well documented on what's named javadoc (java documentation). There you can find every specification of classes, methods, return types, etc, etc, with explanations and sometimes even examples.

In your case, a quick look here would have been really helpful:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation of [`Collections.sort(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)). It  says `Sorts the specified list into ascending order`. It won't return a new sorted list, but instead sort the existing list.

If you want a new sorted list you can use `Stream` or copy the list and then sort the copy.

```
//Stream
List<Student> sortedStudents = students.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

//Copy
List <Student> sortedStudents = new ArrayList<>(students);
Collections.sort(sortedStudents);
```